# Where do php files belong to in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I apologize if my question is pretty straightforward, but I have some hot task and I don't really have much knowledge of PHP nor Wordpress. But I need to know how can I run wordpress website locally with all php files needed to route through it already defined?
Could you tell where do these files belong in Wordpress project and where could I find information that could help me to tune in?

[image]

I have a lot of errors in this files telling that functions are not defined. Having googled function names, I found out that these files use Wordpress functions like get_footer() etc..
It might also help...

Apparently, this site is already running and only uses these files as frontend

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation yet? If not then I'd start there: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/

Answer (score 0):

Those files belong in your theme folder.

`/wp-content/themes/yourtheme`